# Test class simplification without generics

Tags: c#, xunit, autofixture, automoq

I have a large collection of models that all implement `IEquatable<T>` for which I have several similar looking test classes, aside from the SUTs type. The tests validate the implementation and a few other common aspects all implemented by the models under test.

Using an abstract generic test class does not accomplish much, I loose the compile time overload resolution on the operators and I have to implement a derived test class for each type anyway.

Using the `MemberData` attribute helps eliminate the need for derived test classes, however the compile time overload resolution on the operators remains.

Does another approach exist such as `InlineData` where I maintain the compile time overload resolution on the operators and have a single collection of objects (whether they are types or not) to invoke the test methods?

In the example below, I use `MemberData` but must use reflection to invoke the `==` and `!=` operators and the test method signatures are less than optimal as they are unused (only the generic type parameter is used).

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(GetModelTypes))]
public void MyTest<T>(T _)
    where T : class, new()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
    // Add any known type customization's...

    T t = fixture.Create<T>();
    // Implement remaining generic test body.
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetModelTypes() =>
{
    new object[] {new ModelA()},
    new object[] {new ModelB()},
    /* ... */
}
```

Does anyone know a methodology that will allow me to maintain one collection of objects and test with compile time overload resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [write generic unit test classes with xUnit.net](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/09/GenericunittestingwithxUnit.net) like this:

```
public abstract class ModelTests<T>
{
    [Fact]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var sut = fixture.Create<T>();

        // The rest of the test goes here...
    }

    // More tests go here...
}

public class ModelATests : ModelTests<ModelA> { }
public class ModelBTests : ModelTests<ModelB> { }
```

That said, if you have a multitude of similar-looking tests, it may be worthwhile looking into [AutoFixture.Idioms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Idioms), and particularly its `IdiomaticAssertion` base class.

Comment: Ok, that does improve it as I wasn't fond of the ugly test signatures. Right now I use reflection to obtain the `op_Equality` and `op_Inequality` members so I can ensure they produce valid results, any thoughts on a simplification there? I am looking into `IdiomaticAsserts` now.

Comment: @Ritmo2k Yeah, I think you could write the tests in F# and use generic constraints. In C#, I think that you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, having a single static collection for testing different behaviors is kind of suicide. Don't shoot yourself. Secondly, it is not quite clear what you're attempting to achieve except the fact that now having am attribute gives you power to run reflection. If your question was about having reflection all together with generics, then it is indeed possible. Check out something like `typeof(GenericType<>).MakeGenericType(...)`.

Comment: The desire for simplification comes the fact that each test class is line for line the same except for the type declarations. It is as much overhead to maintaining a single collection of types versus one file per type except that I save on code duplication. MemberData allows for that, however my implementation is less than optimal.

Comment: If you got something exact the same with only difference in types, you upgrade your class to be generic. Can't you do that?

Comment: I have updated the question in the hopes to provide clarification.

Comment: > Using an abstract generic test class does not accomplish much, I loose the compile time overload resolution on the operators and I have to implement a derived test class for each type anyway.

Comment: Why so? The whole idea of generics not to duplicate the subclasses.

Comment: It seems to me that the root of the problem is poor design.

Comment: Well, the answer follows the comma in the sentence you quoted:) You cannot invoke an equality operator such as == or != in a generic class and have it resolve to the types implementation. What does happen in a generic class or method is objects implementation is resolved and the types own implementation is ignored. This happens for the reason stated, operator resolution is done at compile time and in a generic, how can the compiler know who's type to dispatch the implementation to?

Comment: Don't invoke shorthands. Wrap them into a normal method with the same signatures.

Comment: The test is a test *on* the implementation of IEquality<T> and hence the operators are part of that implementation and must be valid.

Comment: Nope. You might wrap overload and rely on custom or. NET comparer. Thus nothing specific should ever happen in the operwtor overloads except call to a comparer. Comparers are independent and hence could be tested easily.

Comment: In other words, move out your code from the operators toward testable classes. You might take a glimpse at composition over inheritance to achieve that elegantly.

Comment: I recommend you research that assertion for yourself. Maybe a test case in a debugger might help you.